# How would I format dates of different languages to get the difference between the current day and a day in the future?

Tags: java, android, date, formatting

So the goal is to be able to get the current date (no problem there) and compare it to a date coming in, which can be either the current date or a date in the future. Not only that, but because of how other languages write out or structure dates, the date string that comes in can change format-wise depending on the language.

If the device is set to English, the string comes in like so:

**"Monday, January 30, 2023"**

But if the device is set to French, the string looks like this instead:

**"lundi 30 janvier 2023"**

... and Spanish like this:

**"lunes, 30 de enero de 2023"**

... and so on. Italian is slightly different, and I've also tried German, which is also slightly different.

I did try DateFormat with DateFormat.LONG and Locale.getDefault() as the parameters (so that it would always use the Locale the device is set to and will always get the full date) but it throws an "unparsable date" error for every language, even the English string.

How would I take any of the given strings above and format them in a way that I can compare the date to the current date (a value like LocalDate.now())? Is there an overarching way to do so across languages, or do I need to create formats for all of these? The purpose is to see how far out the date asked for is from the current date to adjust what is visible in my app (done based on days - is the asked for date 3 days out from the current date? 4 days? 5?).

Thanks in advance for any and all help and insight!

Comment: Did you try `DateFormat.FULL`?  The `LONG` format doesn't generally include the day of the week.

Comment: Consider not using `DateFormat` and other date and time classes from the mid-1990s. `DateFormat` is notoriously troublesome, and all those classes are long outdated. See if you can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). You wan classes `LocalDate`, `DateTimeFormatter` and `FormatStyle`.

Comment: Your problem is in architecture.  Nothing should be sending the date as a text string like that.  It should be sending it as an integer (from a predefined time, generally the epoch) or it should be sending it in a predefined format without words, and formatting it on the client side when displayed.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I just tried using FULL instead of LONG, and it appears to work for English and Spanish so far - I'm going to try implementing it at this point, but it seems like changing it to DateFormat.FULL worked.

Comment: @OleV.V. Are you sure the java.time classes include something equivalent to `DateFormat.FULL` or `DateFormat.LONG`?  I've certainly never seen anything that would work for this.

Comment: @GabeSechan is very, very correct. Have the sender send the date in ISO 8601 standard[](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. It goes like `2023-01-30`.

Comment: Yes, @DawoodibnKareem, [I am in no doubt whatsoever](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html).

Comment: Thank you, @OleV.V., I had never seen that Enum before.

Comment: For example `LocalDate.parse("lundi 30 janvier 2023", DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL).withLocale(Locale.FRENCH))` yields `2023-01-30`. Also @DawoodibnKareem

Comment: A further reason for wanting the `LocalDate` class that you also mention in the question is that counting days is so straightforward: `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(today, dateFromUser)`.

Comment: Usage: I think you mean *parse*, that is, convert from string to a date-time object, not *format*, which would be the opposite conversion. I might even suspect that Wijdane KHATTAT misunderstood when answering because you said the opposite of what you meant.

Comment: FYI, you should not be exchanging date-time values as localized text. Use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for textual data exchange and data storage.

Answer (score 0):

You must to configure your dates patterns for each language (Locale) => This output is exactly what you want, try to adapt it with your function need :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale enLocale = Locale.UK;
        String datePatternForEn = "EEEE', 'MMMM', 'dd yyyy";
        Locale frLocale = Locale.FRANCE;
        String datePatternForFr = "EEEE dd MMMM yyyy";
        Locale spLocale = new Locale("es", "ES");
        String datePatternForSp = "EEEE',' dd' de 'MMMM' de 'yyyy";
        DateTimeFormatter englishDateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePatternForEn, enLocale);
        DateTimeFormatter frenchDateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePatternForFr, frLocale);
        DateTimeFormatter spanishDateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePatternForSp, spLocale);
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now().format(englishDateFormat));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now().format(frenchDateFormat));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now().format(spanishDateFormat));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the modern way. *You must to configure your dates patterns for each language* No, this is not necessary. Just use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL).withLocale(desiredLocale)`. May for example specify `Locale.getDefault()`.

Comment: Yes, just check  FormatStyle.FULL if it's compatible with your exactly pattern need.  (FormatStyle.LONG is not compatible cause not containing the day of week)

Comment: You may edit your answer to use this, and your answer will be more useful, I think.